# npm: How to just run postinstall?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

In my node.js project, how could I just run the `postinstall` script, without running install before?

FYI, this is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "gestionclientjs",
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
  ...
  },
  "repository": {},
  "devDependencies": {
  ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall" : "bower install && node ./app/server/dbSeed.js",
    "start": "node app/server/app.js"
  }
}
```

For now, I run :

```
npm install
```

in my project, but I want to run

```
npm postinstall
```

when I want (and when I'm sure dependencies are ok).

Comment: postinstall only runs after install: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: It would be nice if npm-install even documented that postinstall (and maybe more?) scripts are being run...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can run individual script entries using [`npm run SCRIPTNAME`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

```
$ npm run postinstall
```

Comment: @nonox it's special in that it will be run automatically after `npm install`, but it's also "just" another script :-)

Comment: yes, of course ... I don't know why I didn't think about it

Comment: I'm using npm 6.9.0 and `npm install` did not run scripts > postinstall. I have to use this answer command to make it run.

Comment: for npm 6.12.0, postinstall runs automatically.

Comment: @HarshSrivastava sometimes it's useful to manually run `postinstall`

Comment: @robertklep yup! Agreed