# How to explicitly share files part of a NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json

I want to publish a nodejs public repo on github as NPM package, to be installed globally, with

```
npm install -g mypackage
```

The package contains also some executables and some source code files (example programs) in the `example` directory:

```
examples/file_1.js
examples/file_2.js
```

What's the correct way to let access LOCALLY (without access the github repo) these example files, to a user that installed the package?

`examples` files are in directory: `.../node_modules/examples`, I so could suggest to read the files at:

```
echo `npm root -g`/mypackage/examples
```

Make sense? Any cleaner solution?
thx

Comment: Thx. Nevertheless I don't understand how user that installed the package can access (make a copy of) distribution files declared in "files" package.json section.

Comment: Perhaps you could print a message in a `postinstall` script?

Comment: The files will be there in `.../node_modules/yourpackage`.

Comment: @customcommander do you mean by example running with `npm run postinstall` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000392/npm-how-to-just-run-post-install) a bash script like echo "Example files are in directory:"; echo \`npm root -g\`/mypackage/examples ?

Comment: @GiorgioRobino Yep except that you wouldn't need to run it manually. It's automatically done for you _after_ the installation of a package. i.e. after `npm install <your package>`

Comment: The solution I found good for me: as suggested I made a `postinstall` node script that print to stdout a sort of README where I remind package user that examples are under directory  `npm root -g`/mypackage/examples . BTW I do not agree about the fact my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642477/how-to-publish-a-npm-package-with-distribution-files (never mind).